# Adobe CQ AEM: query to fetch pages by passing component name

Tags: adobe, aem, jcr-sql2

I am using Query builder as below to get the list of distinct pages which uses the component (component name will passed as a parameter) in property. I need to pass two parameters, `cq:lastReplicationAction=Activate` and `sling:resourceType=component` path. I tried above JSON query but no result and it is failing since the component may be used at any level of page node. E.g, `/jcr:content/par/component` or `/jcr:content/par/mainpar/component`

> https://host:port/bin/querybuilder.json?1_property=sling:resourceType&1_property.value=COMPONENTPATH&2_property=jcr:content/cq:lastReplicationAction&2_property.value=Activate&path=FROM_WHICH_CONTENT_PATH&type=cq:Page&p.limit=-1

Comment: Provide please real params, may there is wrong components path

Comment: If you need a list of pages with a specific component you can use the OOTB functionality provided at `http://localhost:4502/libs/wcm/core/content/sites/components.html` (see the Live Usage tab) or a lamer (classic ui) version at `http://localhost:4502/etc/reports/compreport.html`

You can also call the underlying _Live Usage_ servlet directly with the resource type: `http://localhost:4502/libs/wcm/core/content/sites/components/details/liveusage.0.40.html/apps/weretail/components/structure/productfilter`

Answer (score 4):

Components are placed under par node of page, and Replication property is part of page JCR node. That's the reason your query is returning 0 result. Try this query:

```
http://localhost:4502/bin/querybuilder.json?1_property=jcr:content/par/*/sling:resourceType&1_property.value=<Component-Path>&2_property=jcr:content/cq:lastReplicationAction&2_property.value=Activate&path=<BASE-Content-Path>&type=cq:Page&p.limit=-1
```

I have used following property to find component: **jcr:content/par/*/sling:resourceType** If your par node has different name then use correct name of par node.

Comment: This will only work for components which are immediate children of the `jcr:content/par` node, and won't include fixed components, or those which are nested inside other components.

Comment: This is a reference query, regex can be changed based on your project hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

A xpath query can be used to get the pages where a components used.

Goto CRXDELight using http://AEM-AUTHOR-HOST/crx/de/index.jsp, open Tools -> Query. Place the query into the Query box:

```
/jcr:root/content//*[jcr:contains(@sling:resourceType, 'COMPONENT_NAME/PATH')] order by @jcr:score
```

if you know exact path of the component then use below query.

```
/jcr:root/content//*[@sling:resourceType =  'COMPONENT_PATH'] order by @jcr:score
```

It will return list of paths of content nodes where your component being used. You may split the each path before `/jcr:content` to get exact page paths.